# Android custom font in titlebar in ListActivity

Tags: android, listactivity, titlebar

I am solving this issue. I need to set up custom font in titlebar, but my activity is using dynamically generated layout (thus `setContentView(R.layout.somtehing`) is not used).

I have tried, that to set up custom font in titlebar you can do that by these code:

```
    type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/verdanab.ttf");
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.something);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.gal_title);

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(R.string.Text);
    title.setTypeface(type);
```

Problem is, this code doesn't work, app doesn't see `TextView` title, because there isn't `setContentView()`. Any advices?

Thx

Comment: We have set title layout using getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.gal_title);

Comment: here is really nice tutorial just for what you have asked http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-create-custom-titlebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize this line  `type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/verdanab.ttf");` after this line

```
 getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.gal_title);
```

Use this code,

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.something);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.gal_title);

    Typeface  type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/verdanab.ttf");
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(R.string.Text);
    title.setTypeface(type);
```

Comment: I wasn't giving you -1, but be sure I have inicialized line you are talking about. This would be beginner programming issue. And surely this is not a solution